# make float:right image display on top of another div using responsive CSS

Tags: css

I have this CSS for displaying a list of products online:

```
.product-box {
    width:100%;
    min-height:200px;
    padding:15px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border:1px solid #666666;
    display:inline-block;
}
.product-box-inner {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width:80%;
}
.product-box-image {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    width:180px;
    height:180px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

and this HTML:

```
<div class="product-box">

    <div class="product-box-image">image</div>
    <div class="product-box-inner">
    <h4><?php echo $product["title"]; ?></h4><br>
    <p><?php echo nl2br(substr($product["description"],0,200)); ?></p><br>
    &pound;<?php echo $product["costprice"]; ?><form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="cart.php"><input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $product["sequence"]; ?>" /><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add to Shopping Cart" /></form>
    </div>

    </div>
```

how can i make the `product-box-image` div display on top of the text in the centre of the `product-box` div when the screen gets too small (using responsive CSS)

Comment: JSFiddle with full HTML code & images please.

Comment: see fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pmdjf/

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of the media queries

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px), only screen and (max-device-width: 700px) {
    .product-box-image {
         display:block !important;
         margin: 0 auto !important; 
           float:none !important;
    }
}
```

This will make the image no longer float right. Tell me know if it works, or setup up a jsfiddle for an accurate answer.

Comment: i didn't notice he had is as an inline element

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working code, make sure your edit the max-width and max-device-width to suit your need

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

http://liveweave.com/2RvC4R

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .product-box-image {
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
     float: none;
  }
}
```